# What do you call a method like this and does an implementation already exist?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, naming-conventions

I recently wrote this method in typescript which takes an array and constructs a map from it.
The keyFunc takes an element from the array and produces a key for the constructed map.
The valFunc takes an element from the array and the previous value from the constructed map and produces a new value to overwrite the previous value with.
The initialValue is the value each entry in the map is initialized with when the first element is mapped to it.

```
private static toMap<X, Y>(
  array: X[],
  keyFunc: (element: X) => string,
  valFunc: (previousValue: Y, element: X) => Y,
  initialValue: Y
): Map<string, Y>
{
  const result = new Map<string, Y>();
  for (const el of array) {
    const key = keyFunc(el);
    let oldVal = result.get(key);
    if (oldVal === undefined) {
      oldVal = initialValue;
    }
    const newVal = valFunc(oldVal, el);
    result.set(key, newVal);
  }
  return result;
}
```

I use the method like this in my code:

```
const countPeopleWithEqualNames = toMap<Person, number>(
  /*array*/ allPeople,
  /*keyFunc*/ person => person.name,
  /*valFunc*/ (previousValue, person) => perviousValue + 1,
  /*initialValue*/ 0
);

const howManyAlices = countPeopleWithEqualNames.get('alice');
```

I would like to know if a method like this already exists in javascript/typescript. I would also like to know how a method like this would be called. It is some kind of merged reduction but I am hoping it has a proper name.

Comment: It is a fold (reduce in JS). Btw., just wrapping your iterative and impure computation in a function doesn't make it functional.

Comment: I don't think this has a common name in functional programming... it's like a [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) operation where the downstream function is a reduce.  So, `groupByAndReduce` or something?  As for the implementation I could imagine rewriting it using functional methods instead of loops but it's all the same, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is what you looking for. Your example could be accomplished with it.

Edit:

```
const toMap = <X, Y>(
    array: X[],
    keyFunc: (element: X) => string,
    valFunc: (previousValue: Y, element: X) => Y,
    initialValue: Y
  ): Map<string, Y> =>
  {
    return array.reduce<Map<string, Y>>((acc, curr) => {
        const key = keyFunc(curr)
        let oldVal = acc.get(key);
        if (oldVal === undefined) {
            oldVal = initialValue;
        }
        const newVal = valFunc(oldVal, curr);
        acc.set(key, newVal);
        return acc
    }, new Map())
  }
```

Comment: I added an example.